# Building apk to debug and release mode without changing Android Google API key each time?

Tags: android, android-build, android-debug

I use **gmaps in my app** and the **api key from a file** looks like:

```
<resources>

<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">

    <!-- DEBUG -->
    <!-- AIzaSyB#####MY_DEBUG_API_KEY_HERE -->

    <!-- RELEASE -->
    AIzaSyBS####MY_RELEASE_KEY_HERE
</string>
```

I wouldn't like to **change beetwen keys each time i build a release because** i could easily forget about it and in that way gmaps wont work in released app.

I taught about using only one key but from almost every source i looked up it is marked as bad practice.

So is there an easy way/option maybe with build type/flavour to somehow made the build process "smart" to :

**When i build in debug mode my build could use the debug api key and vica vera with the release build?**

Comment: Why do you have two API keys in the first place? With the current incarnation of Play Services' maps support (Maps V2), you can associate multiple signing keys with one API key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define resource files in build type specific folders.

For example, in `/app/src/debug/res/values/strings.xml`:

```
<string name="google_maps_key">debug_maps_key_here</string>
```

And in `/app/src/release/res/values/strings.xml`:

```
<string name="google_maps_key">release_maps_key_here</string>
```

The build system will automatically use only the resources for the build type it is currently building, thus using the correct key for each build.